# Laravel mkdir and copy Errors

Tags: php, git, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I'm trying to install a laravel application. This question might be specific to [Wardrobe](http://wardrobecms.com/), or not. I'm not sure. The Laravel application I'm trying to install is called [Wardrobe](http://wardrobecms.com/).

So, there are 2 options that can be used to install this application (or script, I don't know). The first one is with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), and the second one is with git.

I'm trying to install this script to my server for weeks. I failed all the time. I can do this on my local computer, but can't on my server.

So, to tell you the problems, I'm creating two subdomains. One is called w1, and the other one is called w2. I'm trying to install Wardobe to w1 using composer, and I'll use git clone on w2.

I cd into `/var/www/w2.domain.com/` and execute `composer create-project wardrobe/wardrobe public_html`. This creates the project into /var/www/w1.domain.com/public_html.

Then, for w2,

I cd into `/var/www/w2.domain.com/` and execute `git clone https://github.com/wardrobecms/wardrobe.git`

Then, I go into database.php of each folder and write my database information.

Then I execute

```
chmod -R 777 app/storage/

chmod 777 public/img/
```

After all this, I go to w1.domain.com from my browser. I get '500 Internal Server Error', so I update both (w1 and w2) my .htaccess file from [Laravel Installation Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/installation).

Now, I enter to w1.domain.com. I see the Installer Step 1. I click on 'Install Database & Continue'. BAM! Permission denied!

Here's the error message for w1:

```
copy(/var/www/w1.domain.com/public_html/public/packages/wardrobe/core/.gitkeep): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Then I enter w2.domain.com. BAM! Permission denied!

Here's the error message for w2:

```
mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Then I go into w1 and w2 folders and chown all.

Nothing changes.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

1. chmod 777 everything.
2. Install script.
3. Turn privileges to normal values using chmod.
4. End of story.

Thank you everyone for being so helpful.